# Getting view options in Microsoft Project using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-project

If I want to change the current date format to 20, for example, I can use the command

```
OptionsViewEx DateFormat:=20
```

but how can I *get* the current date format (or any other view option for that matter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DefaultDateFormat` should be the function to use.

```
oldvalue = Application.DefaultDateFormat
Application.DefaultDateFormat = 20 ' or = pjDate_mm_dd_yyyy
```

This gets or sets the default date format. ([technet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office.vbapj.chm131711.aspx))

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff867191.aspx) gives the complete list of format types.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Date` function get a date in current format, but if you need change use `format(Date,"yyyy-mmmm-dd")` for example.

Comment: I'm not trying to format a specific date. I'm trying to change the format Project uses to display dates in its GUI, something which is done manually by going to Tools->Options->View->Date format. This is done programmatically by using the OptionsView method, like I demonstrated in my question. What I don't know how to do, is how to programmatically get the current View->Date format setting.